# how bind `C-c g g` to `vc-git-grep`

Tags: key-bindings, prelude, prefix-keys

How can I bind `C-c g g` to `vc-git-grep` ?

So far I tried

```
;; in scratch buffer
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g g") 'vc-git-grep) 
;; then M-x eval-region
;; then switch to another buffer
;; C-c g g
```

Comment: for some reason safari pops up with google browser

Comment: You have *written* both `C-c g g` and also `C-x g g`, so (a) please verify that this is merely a typo in the question; and (b) assuming that is the case, you almost certainly have either `C-c g` or `C-c g g` bound in your config to a command for opening google in a web browser. Use `C-h k C-c g g` to find out what the binding is, and then grep your config for that.

Comment: fixed typo to show as C-c g g

Comment: For clarity, note that `C-c` followed by a letter is a sequence reserved for end-users. While it's not guaranteed, it *shouldn't* be the case that any elisp library has bound that sequence. It *should* be the case that you yourself have done this -- even if unintentionally. (If it turns out to be some third-party library, raise a bug report with the guilty party, and point them at [(elisp) Key Binding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html).)

Comment: From your comment, it sounds like the OS is intercepting your keybinding to launch safari.

Answer (score 0):

## Quick way

You need to make <kbd>C-c g</kbd> a prefix key first:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c g") (make-sparse-keymap))
```

and then bind your key:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c g g") 'vc-git-grep)
```

## Why do you want to create a new prefix key?

Are you going to reuse it?
If *yes*, you should probably go the [official
way](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html):

```
(define-prefix-command 'my-git-prefix-map)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c g") my-git-prefix-map)
(define-key my-git-prefix-map "g" 'vc-git-grep)
```

If *no*, then you probably want to re-use the existing `vc-prefix-map`
(try <kbd>C-x v C-h</kbd> to see the existing bindings).

Comment: None of that is a *necessity*. `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g g") 'vc-git-grep)` will work just fine -- provided that neither `C-c` nor `C-c g` exist already as non-prefix bindings (and assuming `vc-git` is loaded).